# Regularization layer in Keras does' not effect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to write a simple custom layer for regularization in Keras as follow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import Regularizer
import tensorflow as tf

class MyRegularization(Regularizer):
      def __init__(self):
          self.alpha = 100000000

      def __call__(self, w):
          return self.alpha * tf.reduce_sum(w ** 2)
```

as you see the coefficent of regularization is so great. Then, I add this regularization to each layer of a simple network:

```
model = Sequential([
      Dense(1000, activation='relu', input_shape=[10,], kernel_regularizer=MyRegularization()),
      Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=MyRegularization()),
      Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=MyRegularization()),
      Dense(2, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=MyRegularization()),
])
```

I expect that because of a great `alpha` the learning is not converge, but it is look like the value of `alpha` does not affect the training procdeure. Why?

I took the `alpha = 1e-4` but the there is not different when `alpha=1e+10`. :-\

Comment: Following [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py) code, I think it's worth a try replacing the `tf.reduce_sum` with `K.sum` and cast the alpha value to the default Keras float type with `K.cast_to_floatx(alpha)`. Let me know if makes any difference.

Comment: I did what you said but nothing new happens. :'(

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the the class instance

```
MyRegularization()
```

or are you calling an object instance of the class with the same class name?

```
MyRegularization = MyRegularization()
...
MyRegularization()
```

because only the latter one will define the function body (`__call__`) that's carried out when an instance is used as a function. That would explain why the regularization value are not returning, thus looking like the values of  `alpha` are not affecting the training.